# Trim Space on left Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula on Google sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,",","+VITAMIN "),"+"),SPLIT(A2:A,"+"))))
```

How do i remove spaces on left after my split?

You can see example in column F in this example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ZU_mUrnTvhssgHF231dHKFjjsD7t_0pEFm0ysKoL6A/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, how about using `TRIM` as follows?

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,",","+VITAMIN "),"+"),SPLIT(A2:A,"+")))))
```

and

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,",","+VITAMIN "),"+")),TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,"+")))))
```

#### Reference:

- [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)

Comment: @Simon GIS Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.